# Can I use a dictionary in Python to replace multiple characters?

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I am looking for a way to write this code consisely. It's for replacing certain characters in a Pandas DataFrame column.

```
df['age'] = ['[70-80)' '[50-60)' '[60-70)' '[40-50)' '[80-90)' '[90-100)']

df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('[', '')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace(')', '')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('50-60', '50-59')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('60-70', '60-69')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('70-80', '70-79')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('80-90', '80-89')
df['age'] = df['age'].str.replace('90-100', '90-99')
```

I tried this, but it didn't work, strings in df['age'] were not replaced:

```
chars_to_replace = {
    '[' : '',
    ')' : '',
    '50-60' : '50-59',
    '60-70' : '60-69',
    '70-80' : '70-79',
    '80-90' : '80-89',
    '90-100': '90-99'
                  }

for key in chars_to_replace.keys():
    df['age'] = df['age'].replace(key, chars_to_replace[key])
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, I did forget `str` before `replace`. Adding it solved my problem, thank you!

Also, thank you tdelaney for that answer, I gave it a try and it works just as well. I am not familiar with regex substitions yet, I wasn't comfortable with the other options.

Comment: Did you forget `str` before the `replace` call?

Comment: In the second snippet there is no "str." in front of the "replace".

Answer (score 2):

Use two passes of regex substitution.

In the first pass, match each pair of numbers separated by `-`, and decrement the second number.

In the second pass, remove any occurrences of `[` and `)`.

By the way, did you mean to have spaces between each pair of numbers? Because as it is now, implicit string concatenation puts them together without spaces.

```
import re

string = '[70-80)' '[50-60)' '[60-70)' '[40-50)' '[80-90)' '[90-100)'

def repl(m: re.Match):
    age1 = m.group(1)
    age2 = int(m.group(2)) - 1
    return f"{age1}-{age2}"

string = re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', repl, string)
string = re.sub(r'\[|\)', '', string)

print(string)  # 70-7950-5960-6940-4980-8990-99
```

The `repl` function above can be condensed into a lambda:

```
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group(1)}-{int(m.group(2))-1}"
```

**Update:** Actually, this can be done in one pass.

```
import re

string = '[70-80)' '[50-60)' '[60-70)' '[40-50)' '[80-90)' '[90-100)'

repl = lambda m: f"{m.group(1)}-{int(m.group(2))-1}"

string = re.sub(r'\[(\d+)-(\d+)\)', repl, string)

print(string)  # 70-7950-5960-6940-4980-8990-99
```

Comment: Regular expressions are definitely the way to approach multiple replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these brackets are on all of the entries, you can slice them off and then replace the range strings. From the docs, [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace), `pandas` will replace the values from the dict without the need for you to loop.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "age":['[70-80)', '[50-60)', '[60-70)', '[40-50)', '[80-90)', '[90-100)']})

ranges_to_replace = {
    '50-60' : '50-59',
    '60-70' : '60-69',
    '70-80' : '70-79',
    '80-90' : '80-89',
    '90-100': '90-99'}

df['age'] = df['age'].str.slice(1,-1).replace(ranges_to_replace)
print(df)
```

Output

```
     age
0  70-79
1  50-59
2  60-69
3  40-50
4  80-89
5  90-99
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous response, if you want to apply the regex substitution to your dataframe, you can use the `apply` method from `pandas`. To do so, you need to put the regex substitution into a function, then use the `apply` method:

```py
def replace_chars(chars):
    string = re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', repl, chars)
    string = re.sub(r'\[|\)', ' ', string)
    return string
    
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(replace_chars)

print(df)
```

which gives the following output:

```py
                                          age
0   70-79  50-59  60-69  40-49  80-89  90-99
```

By the way, here I put spaces between the ages intervals. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

change the last part to this

```
for i in range(len(df['age'])):
    for x in chars_to_replace:
        df['age'].iloc[i]=df['age'].iloc[i].replace(x,chars_to_replace[x])
```